# [KDB+/Q]: Nested vector conditional

Tags: kdb, q-lang

How to efficiently and concisely switch formulas dependent on the value of other vector?

According to [kx documentation](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#vector-conditional), it is possible to

> have more than just a true/false selection, e.g. match1/match2/match3/others mapping to result1/result2/result3/default

Data:

```
q)t:([]a:til 5;b:10+til 5;c:100+til 5;d:1000+til 5;g:`I`B`I`U`B) 
a b  c   d    g
---------------
0 10 100 1000 I
1 11 101 1001 B
2 12 102 1002 I
3 13 103 1003 U
4 14 104 1004 B
```

I've done it like this:

```
q)update r:(flip (a+b;c+d;a-d))@'`I`B`U?g from t
a b  c   d    g r    
---------------------
0 10 100 1000 I 10   
1 11 101 1001 B 1102 
2 12 102 1002 I 14   
3 13 103 1003 U -1000
4 14 104 1004 B 1108
```

Question - is there more efficient way (time,space,lines of code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to your solution, but seems about 30% faster, possibly because there's no `flip`

```
q)update r: ((a+b;c+d;a-d)@(`I`B`U?g))@'i from t
a b  c   d    g r
---------------------
0 10 100 1000 I 10
1 11 101 1001 B 1102
2 12 102 1002 I 14
3 13 103 1003 U -1000
4 14 104 1004 B 1108

q)t:1000000?t
q)\t update r: ((a+b;c+d;a-d)@(`I`B`U?g))@'i from t
166
q)\t update r:(flip (a+b;c+d;a-d))@'`I`B`U?g from t
248
```

Although the nested conditional still looks faster:

```
q)\t update r:?[`I=g;a+b;?[`B=g;c+d;a-d]] from t
46
```

Comment: `@'i` is brilliant! New idiom to me, before I kept reusing series of `@'` from right to left. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a vector conditional:
http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#vector-conditional

```
    q)update r:?[`I=g;a+b;c+d] from t
     a b  c   d    g r
     --------------------
     0 10 100 1000 I 10
     1 11 101 1001 B 1102
     2 12 102 1002 I 14
     3 13 103 1003 I 16
     4 14 104 1004 B 1108
```

Edit:
If g has more values than two you can extend further with nested conditionals:

```
   q)\t res2:delete idx from`idx xasc raze{[t;idx;it;k] @[d;`idx`r;:;](idxs;
   (+).(d:t idxs:idx[it])k)}[t;group t`g;]./:flip(`I`C`B;(`a`b;`b`c;`c`d))
   122
   q)
   q)\t res3:update r:?[`I=g;a+b;?[`B=g;c+d;a-d]] from t
   59
   q)res3~res2
   1b
```

Comment: edited the question. g can have more values than two

Answer (score 1):

You can use the trusty dictionary. Have your possible values as keys and the functions as values. You could even generate this function dynamically based on the actual population of key values you have in your table. I'm sure this isn't the best in terms of performance.

```
    q)fd:`I`B`C!({(+). x@`a`b};{(+). x@`b`d};{(+). x@`c`d})
    q)update r:{(fd x[`g])x}each t from t
    a b  c   d    g r
    --------------------
    0 10 100 1000 I 10
    1 11 101 1001 B 1012
    2 12 102 1002 I 14
    3 13 103 1003 C 1106
    4 14 104 1004 B 1018
    q)
```

*edit
Faster approach and comparison...

```
    q)t:1000000?t
    q)fd:`I`B`C!({(+). x@`a`b};{(+). x@`c`d};{(+). x@`b`c})
    q)\t res1:update r:{(fd x[`g])x}each t from t
    635
    q)\t res2:delete idx from`idx xasc raze{[t;idx;it;k] @[d;`idx`r;:;](idxs;(+).(d:t idxs:idx[it])k)}[t;group t`g;]./:flip(`I`C`B;(`a`b;`b`c;`c`d))
    79
    q)res1~res2
    1b
    q)
```